# What's the difference between the content approval functionality and the workflow functionality in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

What's the difference between the content approval functionality and the workflow functionality in SharePoint. Can someone help me list some pros and cons too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approval workflow can specify multiple users in a certain order to approve the item.

If any participant rejects the document, the approval workflow can choose to automatically reject the document.

If changes are made before the workflow is completed, approval workflow automatically rejects the document.

Approval workflow could update the approval status after the workflow is completed.

Similar issue for your reference:
[https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116290/difference-between-content-approval-and-document-approval-workflow#:~:text=Document%20Approval%20Workflows%20are%20created,a%20custom%20SharePoint%20Designer%20Workflow.&text=In%20simple%20terms%2C%20when%20Content,to%20others%20until%20it's%20published](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116290/difference-between-content-approval-and-document-approval-workflow#:%7E:text=Document%20Approval%20Workflows%20are%20created,a%20custom%20SharePoint%20Designer%20Workflow.&text=In%20simple%20terms%2C%20when%20Content,to%20others%20until%20it%27s%20published).

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8cd11c3-9a80-4b1a-a406-54634bfdbcd5/approval-workflow-vs-content-approval-feature-on-listlibrary?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious